# CSS with less - define saturation of a color

Tags: css, less

I wondering what the percentage values in that CSS LESS snippet are standing for:

```
@color: #e147d4;
@new_color: hsl(hue(@color), 35%, 77%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect them to be RGB based values.

I did a search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

> HSL and HSV are the two most common cylindrical-coordinate representations of points in an RGB color model.

**Example**

```
@h: hue(#167e8a);
@s: saturation(#167e8a);
@l: lightness(#167e8a);

.foo{
    color: hsl(@h,@s,@l);  
}
```